# Duda sobre conexiones simultaneas en firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una duda sobre las conexiones simultaneas en el plan gratuito de firebase.

Entiendo por conexión simultanea a una petición que se hace cuando hay otra ejecutándose.

En la docu de firebase ponen lo siguiente:

**¿Qué es una "conexión simultánea a la base de datos"?**

Una conexión simultánea se refiere a un dispositivo móvil, una pestaña de navegador o una app de servidor que se conecta a la base de datos. Firebase impone límites estrictos en la cantidad de conexiones simultáneas que puede recibir la base de datos de tu app. Estos límites existen para proteger del abuso tanto a Firebase como a nuestros usuarios.

El límite del plan Spark es de 100 y no se puede aumentar. Los planes Flame y Blaze tienen un límite de 100,000 conexiones simultáneas por base de datos.

Este límite no es el mismo que la cantidad total de usuarios de tu app, ya que no todos los usuarios se conectan a la vez. Si necesitas más de 100,000 
conexiones simultáneas, lee el artículo Cómo escalar con varias bases de datos

**Mi duda puntual es**: conectarse a la vez es lo mismo que tener la app abierta?, o solo al momento de lanzarla?, es decir que pueden tener la app abierta más de 100?

y si hay más de 100 usuarios en la app y a la vez más de 100 realizan una consulta a la base de datos, estas se ponen en cola cuando termine con la de los primeros 100 o la app chrasea?

[image: Real time database Firebase]

Gracias

Comment: Son 100 conexiones de cualquier dispositivo de forma simultanea , pueden haber miles de clientes conectados pero simultaneamente solo llega hasta 100 en la version Gratuita

Comment: podes leer esto es muy bueno https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conexiones simultaneas se refiere específicamente a conexiones que se realizan al mismo tiempo.

Puedes tener una cantidad de usuarios usando la aplicación pero no todos realizando la conexión a la base de datos, esto es lo que precisamente indica la documentación:

> [**Una conexión simultánea se refiere a un dispositivo móvil, una
>   pestaña de navegador o una app de servidor que se conecta a la base de
>   datos. Esto no es lo mismo que la cantidad total de usuarios de tu
>   app, ya que no todos los usuarios se conectan a la vez.** Por ejemplo,
>   las apps con 10,000,000 de usuarios activos al mes tienen menos de
>   100,000 conexiones simultáneas. La cantidad máxima de conexiones
>   simultáneas depende del recuento total de usuarios y del tiempo
>   promedio que los usuarios pasan en tu app.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits?hl=en)

---

> Mi duda puntual es: conectarse a la vez es lo mismo que tener la app
>   abierta?, o solo al momento de lanzarla?, es decir que pueden tener la
>   app abierta más de 100?

**Depende de lo que realice tu aplicación**, suponiendo dos ejemplos:

1) Tu una aplicación solo realiza la conexión a la base de datos al acceder a determinada Activity, pero no al iniciar tu aplicación.

2) Tu aplicación es un Chat que al iniciar realiza una conexión a la base de datos.

En el primer caso no podemos considerar que el usuario siempre se encontrará realizando una conexión a la base de datos, ya que no se puede asegurar siempre se encuentre accediendo a la Activity que realiza la conexión a la base de datos, mientras que en el segundo caso definitivamente estará conectado ya que los cambios que realiza el o los demás usuarios conectados al chat se deben sincronizar en milisegundos.

> si hay más de 100 usuarios en la app y a la vez más de 100 realizan
>   una consulta a la base de datos, estas se ponen en cola cuando termine
>   con la de los primeros 100 o la app chrasea?

**Primeramente el "Plan Spark" no te permitiría realizar más de 100 conexiones simultaneas y no, no se ponen en cola.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Las conexiones simultaneas se cuentan por usuario/app conectada a firebase y en uso en ese preciso momento, podrian ser 100 personas usando la app en ese mismo momento. Cuando superes las 100 conexiones simultaneas las primeras 100 en conectarse permaneceran funcionando pero de la 101 en adelante firebase simplemente no respondera los datos solicitados a la base de datos y devolvera un codigo de error, eso no significa que el usuario vea un crash, pero si que no podra interactuar con la base de datos. El error lo podes manejar para mostrarle al usuario lo que creas conveniente. Ya sea un mensaje de error de conexion, una pantalla vacia, etc.

La respuesta mas puntual seria que pueden tener 100 personas la app abierta al mismo tiempo. Las demas solo recibiran mensajes de error al no poder conectarse.